# Monotouch -- Changing label text in ViewController from another class?

Tags: xamarin.ios, label, tcpclient

I have a class that functions as an async TCP Client.  In that class, I have a callback function, such as Client_Connected.  This fires when my TCP Client has been connected.  In my main viewcontroller class, I have an instance of the TCPClient and a label that I want to display the status of the tcpclient.

My question is, in the callback function of the tcpclient class, how can I reference and set the label's text in my mainviewcontroller's class?

Answer (score 0):

When you create your TCPClient class, pass in a reference to your parent class (or just a reference to the label you want to update) - then your "child" class will have access to the element on the "parent" that needs to be updated.

There are probably other approaches, but this is fairly common.